# how to use different forms in one blade file in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 5.6 and I am developing auto classifieds web application. in My app I have 3 different vehicle categories as car, van, truck and I have blade file to select this three different vehicle types. when I select this vehicles my urls show like this,

```
http://localhost:8000/post-ad/Truck/8 <- this is category id

http://localhost:8000/post-ad/van/7

http://localhost:8000/post-ad/Car/5
```

now when I clicked one of above vehicle category page redirect to show.blade.php file, so, now I need 3 different forms to submit data to each vehicles, this is my vehicles form, car form

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            {{csrf_field()}}

            <input type="hidden" id="cid" name="cid" value="{{ $catagories->id }}" />
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">District</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="district">

        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Town</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="town">

        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Brand</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="brand">

        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Model</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="model">

        </select>
        </div>
</form>
```

van form

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            {{csrf_field()}}

            <input type="hidden" id="cid" name="cid" value="{{ $catagories->id }}" />
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">District</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="district">

        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Town</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="town">

        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Brand</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="brand">

        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Model</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="model">

        </select>
        </div>
</form>
```

Truck Form

```
 <form method="post" action="{{url('form')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                {{csrf_field()}}

                <input type="hidden" id="cid" name="cid" value="{{ $catagories->id }}" />
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">District</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="district">

            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Town</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="town">

            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Brand</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="brand">

            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Model</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="model">

            </select>
            </div>
    </form>
```

I need show each form when some user click each vehicle links on one blade file. how can I do this?

Comment: you can simply create a single Form and add html `select` for vehicle types

Comment: cant because this is some example I have different data in different forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add name to your routes, for example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post-ad'], function () {
   Route::get('Truck/{id}', 'TruckController@fetch')->name('track');
   Route::get('Van/{id}', 'VanController@fetch')->name('van');
   Route::get('Car/{id}', 'CarController@fetch')->name('car');
})
```

Put your form to another files like:

```
truck-form.blade.php
van-form.blade.php
car-form.blade.php
```

In your view:

```
@if(request()->route()->getName() = 'track')
    @include('truck-form')
@elseif(request()->route()->getName() = 'van')
    @include('van-form')
@elseif
    @include('van-form')
@endif
```

Comment: where should I put this if else conditins? in my show.blade.php file according to my question?

Comment: one problem here. I am using my route as this **http://localhost:8000/post-ad/van/7** van means category name and 7 is category id. then, How can I put my route according to your answer like **Route::get('Truck/{id}', 'TruckController@fetch')->name('track');**

Comment: @banda update answer, just user group with prefix, i think you need reed more about routes in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Comment: ok , I got route but still have some problem with controller I have created controllers for vehicles but no an idea to put **fetch** methods here.. actually I am new to the laravel

Comment: public function fetch($id) { $car = Car::where('id', $id)->first(), return view('show', ['vehicle' => $car]); }